# Change function not being hit on page reload

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a `cshtml` view which, in the head, declares an js doc and in the body loads a partial

```
<head>
    <script src="~/js/Project/doc.js"></script>
</head>
```

and the partial

```
<div class="panel" id="panelDoc">
    <partial name="_docInformation" model=Model.Doc />
</div>
```

This partial loads up a partial view which has various tables and a dropdown. The doc.js has the following function which simply gets the information on the page again in correspondence to the document type the user has selected, replacing the html in `panelDoc`  to the partial with the new information:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#docType').change(function () {
        debugger;
        // Get the selected document type from the dropdown via ID
        var docType = $('#docType option:selected').val();

        var form = {
            ProjectID: $('#ProjectID').val(),
            DocType: docType
        };

        $.ajax({
            url:  '/Project/LoadDocumentPartial',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success != undefined && !result.success) {
                    // Show error stuff
                }
                else {
                    // Replace the current html in id with new html
                    $('#panelDoc').html(result);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This works the first time the partial is loaded as I can change the dropdown and it hits this function, replacing the contents with the new information. However, if I then change the dropdown again, it never hits this function.

From my understanding, we include the js file in the parent view and this should be hit every time the dropdown changes? Or is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use different syntax for a top of  javascript function:

```
 
 $(document).on("change", "#docType", (function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

......
```

Comment: Seems to work. Any reason why the original didn't?

Comment: When I am using a partial views with ajax I always use this syntax. Another one was never working for me too. When you reload partial view the previous event bindings are getting lost. So you have to bind the event to the document.